# How to change the point about which a rigged object rotates?

Tags: rigging, bones

*I am having trouble describing this. If anyone could give me the correct terms I would be happy to edit my post, etc.*

---

Currently, I am rigging a revolver -- during the reload of a revolver the barrel opens -- but the issue is I need it to open along a certain point -- (see comments for pictures) but instead the revolver folds up per se.

**Current result when rotating barrel:**

[image]

**Desired result when rotating barrel:**

[image]

**Where it needs to be rotated along:**

[image]

Would I simply make a bone at the point of rotation and then parent the barrel to that bone, or am I supposed to use constraints?

Thanks.
Here is the .blend file -- https://a.pomf.cat/hqygla.blend

Comment: Current result when rotating barrel: http://puu.sh/pvTbf/208811e514.jpg

Desired result when rotating barrel: http://puu.sh/pvTdq/71abf8d45c.png

Where it needs to be rotated along: http://puu.sh/pvKra/a373efb1ac.png

Answer (score -1):

I simply had to move the bone position!
[image]

Comment: Or simply add another bone to connect the big bone and root bone, then parent them one after another. Then you can rotate the new bone, that's it.